# FFMPEG: decode h264 with multiple frames

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Please excuse my knowledge of video decoding, I am new to this.

I need to decode video frames from h264 to bitmap images in C#. I am using [FFmpeg.AutoGen](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen) for this. But unfortunately, I failed to get any results.

I have the following data at my disposal.

- *nFrameType* = IFrame, PFrame or BFrame
- *nSequence* = Frame sequence
- *nWidth* = width of resolution
- *nHeight* = Height of resolution
- *nVideoSize* = size of video data
- *pVideo* = video data

My method at current is the following (Similar to the example shown [here](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example/VideoStreamDecoder.cs)):

**initialization**

```
private unsafe AVCodecContext* _codecContext;
private unsafe AVFormatContext* _formatContext;
private unsafe AVFrame* _frame;
AVCodecID codecID;
private unsafe AVCodec* _avCodec;
private bool decoderInitialized = false;

    if (!decoderInitialized)
    {
        if (nCodecType == 2)
        {
            codecID = AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        }
        unsafe
        {
            _avCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_decoder(codecID);
            _codecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(_avCodec);
            ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(_codecContext, _avCodec, null);
            _frame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
        }
        decoderInitialized = true;

    }
```

**decoding**

```
            AVPacket packet;
            ffmpeg.av_init_packet(&packet);
            packet.data = (byte*)pVideo;
            packet.size = (int)nVideoSize;
            int isFrameFinished = 0;

            int response = ffmpeg.avcodec_decode_video2(_codecContext, _frame, &isFrameFinished, &packet);
```

I always get `response = -22` and `isFrameFinished = 0`. I do have a hunch that I am doing something wrong here. But I am unable to find a resource to guide me in some direction. E.g. I know, I need to use nFrameType (IFrame, BFrame and PFrame). But I don't know how? Further, I know that I need to use width and height to decode the image properly, but again, I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: The frame type etc will be in the NAL header so you actually don't have to set it explicitly. What is the format of `pVideo` ?

Comment: It is a byte array. There is no mention of it having any headers. The device API that I am using expects to send other formats too. i.e. H264, MJPEG, MPEG4 and VP8. So, I expect `pVideo` to be just byte array of frame data. And frame type information separate.

Comment: In H.264 the frame type etc is stored in the first bytes of the NAL.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, You don't see anything else wrong with this method?

Answer (score 1):

luckily, I resolved the issue.
I was missing registration of codecs `ffmpeg.avcodec_register_all()` before `ffmpeg.avcodec_find_decoder(codecID)`. Hope it helps others.